# How to get a product / variant "committed" inventory?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

**Problem:**

On the Shopify Admin, section Products > Inventory, there's a "committed" inventory.
[image: Shopify inventory]
Based on my comprehension it means "reserved stock for pending orders", or "inventory reserved by orders created but not yet completed".

This "committed" stock value can be very useful for stock updates by app. But pratically this value seems hard to retreive.

**Question:**

How to get this "committed" inventory value in an efficient way ?

Current state of researchs :

- Not possible via Shopify APIs (REST & GraphQL, version 2022-07)
- Can be approximated (not sure it's the right method) by looping over all unfulfilled orders, and sum up (by variant) the unfulfilled product variant quantity. However, it takes time and consumes a lot of API resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible now in the `2023-01` version of the API. The InventoryLevel got a new field [`quantities`](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/objects/InventoryLevel#field-inventorylevel-quantities), which returns this for a product with a total stock of 10 and two sold:

```
[
  {
    "quantity": 8,
    "name": "available"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 2,
    "name": "committed"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 0,
    "name": "incoming"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 10,
    "name": "on_hand"
  },
  {
    "quantity": 0,
    "name": "reserved"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I discovered it this morning too. Added +1 for the effort but I will accept a more complete answer (with query)